# Azure Polybase External Table on Blob storage file not found

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse, polybase

thanks in advance for your assistance! I have CSV files on Blob storage that are currently successfully being read via polybase in Synapse (Azure SQL DWH).  The method is as described in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analytics-platform-system/polybase-configure-azure-blob-storage?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7).  I have added a new folder (in the same container as the other files) and I get the following error message when creating the external table via SSMS on Synapse:

*Msg 105002, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
External file access failed because the specified path name '/USA/FCT.CSV' does not exist. Enter a valid path and try again.*

If I place the file in another folder, (in the same container), (eg '/CA/FCT.CSV'), which I know I can access files from, it works without issue.  I feel I've proven the file has no issues and external table creation script is error free.

My troubleshooting makes me think a permission setting needs to be set on the folder in the BLOB storage container.  I have checked that the 'Manage Access' settings are the same as a folder with functioning access. What else can I check?

[Blob storage container and folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN9Cc.png)

Full path of the file with worked, (sensitive information replaced with asterisk):
https://***datalake.dfs.core.windows.net/marketing/CA/FCT.CSV

Full path of the file that didn’t work: https://***datalake.dfs.core.windows.net/marketing/USA/FCT.CSV

This is the create table script that did work:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [Nielsen].[USA_Fact_external]
(

[HRCH LVL]                  VARCHAR(40)
,[**** TOTAL MARKET1]       VARCHAR(40)
,[**** COMPANY]         VARCHAR(40)
,[**** BRAND]               VARCHAR(40)
,[**** SEGMENT]         VARCHAR(40)
,[**** TYPE]                VARCHAR(40)
,[**** PACK TYPE]           VARCHAR(40)
,[**** SUB BRAND]           VARCHAR(40)
,[**** ACTUAL PACK SIZE]    VARCHAR(40)
,[PRDC CODE]                    VARCHAR(40)
,[**** TOTAL MARKET22]  VARCHAR(40)
,[MARKET CODE]              VARCHAR(40)
,[PERIOD DESCRIPTION LONG]  VARCHAR(40)
,[UNITS]                        BIGINT 
,[EQ1]                      BIGINT
,[DOL]                      BIGINT
,[AVG UNIT PRICE]           BIGINT
,[AVG EQ1 PRICE]                BIGINT
,[PCTACV]                   BIGINT
,[EST ACV SELLING]          BIGINT
,[ANY PROMO UNITS]          BIGINT
,[ANY PROMO DOL]                BIGINT
,[TDP]                      BIGINT
,[TDP YA]                   BIGINT
,[BASE DOL]                 BIGINT
,[BASE UNITS]               BIGINT
,[BASE EQ]                  BIGINT
,[ANY PROMO EQ]             BIGINT
,[FEAT WO DISP PCTACV]      BIGINT
,[NUMBER OF STORES]         BIGINT
,[NUMERICAL DISTRIBUTION]   BIGINT
)
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = [AzureDataLakeStorage],LOCATION = N'/CA/FCT.CSV',FILE_FORMAT = [CsvFileFormat_withHeadersPipeDL],REJECT_TYPE = VALUE,REJECT_VALUE = 0)
GO
```

This is the create table script that didn't work:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [Nielsen].[USA_Fact_external]
(

[HRCH LVL]                  VARCHAR(40)
,[**** TOTAL MARKET1]       VARCHAR(40)
,[**** COMPANY]         VARCHAR(40)
,[**** BRAND]               VARCHAR(40)
,[**** SEGMENT]         VARCHAR(40)
,[**** TYPE]                VARCHAR(40)
,[**** PACK TYPE]           VARCHAR(40)
,[**** SUB BRAND]           VARCHAR(40)
,[**** ACTUAL PACK SIZE]    VARCHAR(40)
,[PRDC CODE]                    VARCHAR(40)
,[**** TOTAL MARKET22]  VARCHAR(40)
,[MARKET CODE]              VARCHAR(40)
,[PERIOD DESCRIPTION LONG]  VARCHAR(40)
,[UNITS]                        BIGINT 
,[EQ1]                      BIGINT
,[DOL]                      BIGINT
,[AVG UNIT PRICE]           BIGINT
,[AVG EQ1 PRICE]                BIGINT
,[PCTACV]                   BIGINT
,[EST ACV SELLING]          BIGINT
,[ANY PROMO UNITS]          BIGINT
,[ANY PROMO DOL]                BIGINT
,[TDP]                      BIGINT
,[TDP YA]                   BIGINT
,[BASE DOL]                 BIGINT
,[BASE UNITS]               BIGINT
,[BASE EQ]                  BIGINT
,[ANY PROMO EQ]             BIGINT
,[FEAT WO DISP PCTACV]      BIGINT
,[NUMBER OF STORES]         BIGINT
,[NUMERICAL DISTRIBUTION]   BIGINT
)
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = [AzureDataLakeStorage],LOCATION = N'/USA/FCT.CSV',FILE_FORMAT = [CsvFileFormat_withHeadersPipeDL],REJECT_TYPE = VALUE,REJECT_VALUE = 0)
GO
```

This is the external data source script, (sensitive information replaced with asterisk):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [AzureDataLakeStorage_Marketing] WITH (TYPE = HADOOP, LOCATION = N'abfss://marketing@***datalake.dfs.core.windows.net', CREDENTIAL = [******])
```

[Screenshot of the scoped credential entry (sys.database_scoped_credentials)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZktd.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you share the specific SQL code used for the working and failing commands and maybe a screenshot of the blob storage folders in question? Please don’t include credentials in the code.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I've added the extra details.

Comment: Could you add the code for the external data source? What was the full path of the file with worked and the full path of the file that didn’t work? What was the external table code for the one which did work?

Comment: Thanks again Greg, I've added that all in the post.

Comment: Peeling back the onion... what kind of a credential are you using? Storage account key? AAD service principal? Something else? Assuming the USA file exists (which I can’t tell from the screenshot) I’m fairly convinced it’s a permissions issue.

Comment: Also, please check if there are any extra blank spaces in the container names. Let us know if it is working for any other container as well other than USA.

Comment: I've added a sceenshot of the credentials in sys.database_scoped_credentials.  The USA file does exist!  I have double checked there are no extra blank spaces in the container or file names.  If I place the USA file in the 'CA' folder, it works without issue.

Comment: @dsol what kind of credential is it? If it is a service principal make sure the user has Storage Blob Data Contributor on the storage account or container as an easy way to ensure they have access to all files. If file or level permissions were used it’s very easy to not get those right.

Comment: I didn't setup the scoped credentials, I'm trying to work out how I can find out what type it is.  I suspect it is using folder level permissions.